# jpa named query using foreign key is not working

Tags: jpa, named-query

MY Entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(catalog = "", schema = "MYIS")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Answers.findAll", query = "SELECT a FROM Answers a"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Answers.findByAid", query = "SELECT a FROM Answers a WHERE a.aid = :aid"),
    @NamedQuery(name ="Anaswers.findByqid", query ="SELECT a FROM Answers a WHERE a.answerQid.qid = :x"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Answers.findByAnsValue", query = "SELECT a FROM Answers a WHERE a.ansValue = :ansValue"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Answers.findByAnsDate", query = "SELECT a FROM Answers a WHERE a.ansDate = :ansDate")})
public class Answers implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Integer aid;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 4000)
    @Column(name = "ANS_VALUE", nullable = false, length = 4000)
    private String ansValue;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "ANS_DATE", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date ansDate;
    @JoinColumn(name = "A_USERID", referencedColumnName = "USERID", nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Users aUserid;
    @JoinColumn(name = "ANSWER_QID", referencedColumnName = "QID", nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Questions answerQid;
    @JoinColumn(name = "A_GROUPID", referencedColumnName = "GID", nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Groups aGroupid;

    public Answers() {
    }

    public Answers(Integer aid) {
        this.aid = aid;
    }

    public Answers(Integer aid, String ansValue, Date ansDate) {
        this.aid = aid;
        this.ansValue = ansValue;
        this.ansDate = ansDate;
    }

    public Integer getAid() {
        return aid;
    }

    public void setAid(Integer aid) {
        this.aid = aid;
    }

    public String getAnsValue() {
        return ansValue;
    }

    public void setAnsValue(String ansValue) {
        this.ansValue = ansValue;
    }

    public Date getAnsDate() {
        return ansDate;
    }

    public void setAnsDate(Date ansDate) {
        this.ansDate = ansDate;
    }

    public Users getAUserid() {
        return aUserid;
    }

    public void setAUserid(Users aUserid) {
        this.aUserid = aUserid;
    }

    public Questions getAnswerQid() {
        return answerQid;
    }

    public void setAnswerQid(Questions answerQid) {
        this.answerQid = answerQid;
    }

    public Groups getAGroupid() {
        return aGroupid;
    }

    public void setAGroupid(Groups aGroupid) {
        this.aGroupid = aGroupid;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (aid != null ? aid.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Answers)) {
            return false;
        }
        Answers other = (Answers) object;
        if ((this.aid == null && other.aid != null) || (this.aid != null && !this.aid.equals(other.aid))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "com.entity.Answers[ aid=" + aid + " ]";
    }

}
```

MY SESSION FACADE

```
import com.entity.Answers;
import com.entity.Groups;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;

/**
 *
 * @author krishna teja
 */
@Stateless
public class AnswersFacade extends AbstractFacade<Answers> implements AnswersFacadeLocal {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "My_communityPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }

    public AnswersFacade() {
        super(Answers.class);
    }

 public List<Answers> getdataByQid(Long qid){


     Query query=em.createNamedQuery("Answers.findByqid");
     query.setParameter(1, qid);
     List<Answers> a =query.getResultList();
        return a;

 }


}
```

My managed bean

```
     @PostConstruct
      public void init(){

            questions = questionsFacade.findAll();
            ansList = answersFacade.getdataByQid(g);

            }
```

I am getting following exception

```
at com.ejb.AnswersFacade.getdataByQid(AnswersFacade.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
```

I have created named query for the foreign key attribute answerQid and and created method in the sessionfacade and tried to access it in the managed bean the default methods work perfectly but my method for query is not working please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a simple typo. Named query is defined as `Anaswers.findByqid`, but used as `Answers.findByqid`.

Comment: You're welcome. Next time please post the actual exception instead of just part of the stack trace. Good thing it was easy to spot the issue without it.